# no module named 'firebase_admin' using uvicorn main:app --reload

Tags: firebase, api, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI so I run the code with uvicorn main:app --reload, however, I have also a Firebase implementation and when I run the code I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'`

Even though I already checked in the interpreter packages installed and everything. Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Check with pip list if firebase module is installed. Also provide the pip install command as well as the python code with the import firebase_admin line

Comment: Already checked the pip list but "firebase_admin" is in the list. The pip command I used was "pip install --upgrade firebase-admin". The import lines used are: import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

Comment: hi, can you tell us what version of Python and what version of the firebase admin are you using, looking around I found [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/python#version_500_-_28_april_2021) release notes that say that python 3.5 will not be supported by firebase admin 5.0.0, maybe that could be the root of the issue

Comment: Hi, I'm using Python 3.8.6, thanks :(

Comment: and what version of the firebase admin are you using ?